# Submit form to a file located in plugin directory

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

i am creating a WordPress plugin where the plugin provides a shortcode to print an html form in a post or page ,

my question is that

is this a secure and efficient way to store the form action file in plugin directory .

like this .

`<form action="http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/mypluginDir/action.php" method="post">`

if it's not secure and efficient then please guide me what is the right way to post that form. where the action file should be located .

Comment: I think `YES`. Because direct path may be secured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing the `action` attribute for the form is the "better" way. there should be no problem security-wise.